# Magento - Change/Add Reply to for Order Confirmation Emails

Tags: magento

I am looking to modify either the from email address I receive as the admin for order confirmations to be the clients or add a reply-to with the customers email.

I have been looking around and haven't had any luck. I would appreciate some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order emails are sales related emails which can be modified in sales section of magento admin.

have a look on the images. Modify these email addresses according to comfort.

In the Order field set, configure the following options:

To configure sales emails sent to customers:

1. In the Admin Panel, select System > Configuration > SALES > Sales Emails.
2. In the Current Configuration Scope drop-down list in the left upper left corner, select the scope for which you want these configurations to apply.
3. Click the Order heading to expand the Order field set
4. In the Order field set, configure the following options:

   1. In the Enabled drop-down list, select Yes to enable new order confirmation emails to be sent.
   2. In the New Order Confirmation Email Sender drop-down list, select the email address to be used for sending the new order confirmation.
   3. In the New Order Confirmation Template drop-down list, select the template to be used for the for the order confirmation emails sent to registered customers.
   4. In the New Order Confirmation Template for Guest drop down- list, select the template to be used for the for the order confirmation emails sent to guest customers.
   5. In the Send Order Email Copy To field, specify the email address to which a copy of the new order confirmation email is sent. This feature helps you to keep track of the new orders that come in.
5. Configure the options on the other field sets on this page.
6. Click Save Config to save your changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see that I can specify an email address that they come from but I want each one to be coming from or have a reply to email address that is from that specific customer's email for their order. So they are unique for each order confirmation the admin receives.

Thank you

Comment: @Kevin : is that help you?

Comment: Hi urfusion. That does help. Thank you!